# How to get all the fields and properties as well as values when catching exceptions

Tags: c#, exception, reflection

In addition to capturing an exception and logging it I am trying to get all the field and property names and values belonging to the class in which the exception was thrown. This data will then be logged and sent to me by my clients.

This information can be obtained within the catch block of the culprit method's try/catch using Reflection however how can I get the data specific to the class if the exception is not caught within that catch block.

I am catching all program wide exceptions at startup.

**Edit:**
I am trying to retrieve class properties from the Global Exception catch and it would seem that this is not possible. I will accept "this is not possible" as an answer if that is the case.

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Comment: An exception doesn't include "which object?" as a property, so if you're not doing this yourself at the point it is thrown or caught (and presumably rethrown): you can't.

Comment: You can create a crash dump when an exception happens, but that's a bit more tricky than just querying exception properties.

Comment: In short, you shouldn't need to do this (even if you could). Use a good logging framework, set up some verbose logging, and you should able to figure everything that is needed to solve your problem. A Global Exception handler should be to keep your application alive when all else fails, not a tool to debug your application.